# Make min priority queue of arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, priority-queue

I want a min priority queue which instead of containing integers, stores arrays. The priority of each element is the first element in the array.

```
priority_queue<array<int, 6>, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;
array<int, 6> arr = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
pq.push(arr);
array<int, 6> popArr = pq.pop();
```

When I do this I get the following error related to pushing:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::priority_queue<std::array<int, 6>, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> >::push(std::array<int, 6>&)’
 pq.push(arr);
```

And the following related to popping:

```
conversion from ‘void’ to non-scalar type ‘std::array<int, 6>’ requested
 array<int, 6> popArr = pq.pop();
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: 1) Where do you define a comparator that compares the first elements of two arrays? 2) `pop` does not return anything, so your assignment `= pq.pop()` does not make any sense. Have you checked the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop)? 3) How can an underlying container for priority queue _of arrays_ be `std::vector<int>`? Value type for your priority queue is `std::array<int, 6>`, so both underlying container and comparator must reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the type of data structure in priority queue is array<int,6>, so vector<int> should be written as vector<array<int,6>>.

Now the third argument is comparator. So lets create a comparator :

```
struct Compare{
    bool operator()(array<int,6> a,array<int,6> b){
    return a[0]>b[0];
}
};
```

Now declaration looks like:

```
priority_queue<array<int,6>, vector<array<int,6>, Compare > pq;
```

Also, pq.pop() return type is **void**, So it should be **pq.top()** and then write pq.pop() to remove element from priority queue .

Answer (score 2):

From [[container.adaptors]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.adaptors)

> The first template parameter `T` of the container adaptors shall denote the same type as `Container​::​value_­type`.

You need `std::priority_queue<std::array<int, 6>, std::vector<std::array<int, 6>>, greater_first>`, where `greater_first` is a type with a `bool operator()(const std::array<int, 6> &, const std::array<int, 6> &)`, e.g.

```
struct greater_first {
    bool operator()(const std::array<int, 6> & lhs, const std::array<int, 6> & rhs) const {
        return lhs[0] > rhs[0];
    }
};
```

Additionally, `pop` returns `void`, so you have to take the first element before `pop`ping

```
auto popArr = pq.top();
pq.pop();
```